# Sqlalchemy compare a list with a query in order to update, delete and add

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a list of dictionaries that I would like to compare with a table using Sqlalchemy.

I'm looking for an efficient solution to compare in such a way that I can separate the results into 3 groups:

- Those in the table and not the list to be deleted
- Those in both the table and the list to be updated
- Those in the list but not the table to be added

These are options I've looked at but don't think are optimum:

1. Do a query for each item in the list, update/add where appropriate then do a negated any query for those in the table and not the list to be deleted.
2. Query all in the table then some implementation of "set(query) & set(list)" to create a matching list, remove items in the matching list from the initial list and query to create an add and delete list respectively, use these list to update/add/delete

```
class Widgets(model):
    name = Column(String)
    quantity = Column(Integer)
```

```
|----------------|------------------|
|      name      |     quantity     |
|----------------|------------------|
|      foo       |        2         |
|----------------|------------------|
|      far       |        4         |
|----------------|------------------|
```

```
list = [
    {'name': 'foo', 'quantity': 3 },
    {'name': 'bar', 'quantity': 7 }
]
```

Using the above example, foo has an updated quantity of 3, bar is added to the table and far removed.

Answer (score 0):

there is how I will handle this:

Elements to delete: `select element from TABLE where element not in (list_from_dict)`

Elements to update: `select element from TABLE where element in (list_from_dict)`

Elements to add: `list_from_dict` - `result of the select for elements to update`